# Is it possible to override fan control settings directly through REGEDIT?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, fan, cooling, speedfan

I have a Dell Latitude e6420 and the fan noise is driving me crazy. I took the entire fan assembly apart and it is clean as a whistle, but still making obnoxiously loud noise regularly.

I believe this to be due to the PWM throttling too low or fluctuating. I don't mind the sound of the fan at full speed, just the rumbling noise it makes when spinning at low speeds.

Here's what I have tried so far, unsuccessfully:

1. **cleaning the fan** - It's immaculate but still noisy
2. **BIOS fan control override** - I updated to the latest BIOS version (A25) and it does not provide any fan control settings
3. **Dell Power Manager** - It has a menu for "*Thermal Management*", but my Power Plan does not give me the option to modify thermal settings.
4. **Power Options** - I'm using a *High Performance* power plan in hopes that it could run the fans at full speed always. "*System Cooling*" setting is on "*Active*"
5. **SpeedFan 4.49** - It's installed and shows me the fan's speed in RPM. It seems to be most noisy when it drops below 2000. Manually adjusting the PWM and attempts to make a full speed fan controller from the settings does not seem to change the speed. I'm not convinced that the program even manages to take control over the fan speed on my computer. No configuration seems to work.

I have run out of ideas. I read somewhere that there is a registry that controls cooling, but I could not find anything definitive. I'm comfortable modifying registries, but only when I'm confident that it is being done correctly.

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm happy to provide any specific details if it helps diagnose and remedy the noise issue.

Comment: Speedfan (which I see you tried) is probably one of the best software options. Even if you find some setting that adjusts the PWM signal, that is what Speedfan is doing as well. You could also try either buying a fan controller (lets you control the speeds with a knob or more advance ones) or buy quieter fans with similar CFM ratings

Comment: @EricF, I can try playing around with the settings some more with SpeedFan. Hardware options will be limited since it's in a laptop. One hardware hack that I'm considering is snipping the PWM wire and letting it run on 100% duty cycle. I already tested the fan on a bench supply and it seems to run full bore when the PWM signal is absent

Comment: @ToddShimkus That is exactly how it would run. PWM tells the fan how much to run less than 100% at. Definitely an option